# R: Using wait=FALSE in system() with multiline commands

Tags: r

I have a long running process (written in Java) that I wish to run asynchronously with system(..., wait=FALSE). In order to be able to determine when the process has ended i want to create a file afterwards as per the suggestions given in [How to determine when a process started with system(..., wait=FALSE) has ended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242704/how-to-determine-when-a-process-started-with-system-wait-false-has-ended?noredirect=1#comment37448528_24242704). The problem is that it seems the wait parameter only applies to the last line in a multiline system command, and I can't seem to find a way around that.

Example:

```
system('sleep 2')                 # waits 2 seconds before control is returned to the user
system('sleep 2', wait=FALSE)     # control is returned immediately
system('sleep 2; ls', wait=FALSE) # waits 2 seconds before control is returned to the user
```

I'm running on a mac system btw...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find strange that R's system only waits for the first command (it should be calling the shell, which then waits for both commands) but using && should do it:

```
system('sleep 2 && ls', wait=FALSE)
```

If R is appending a & to the command line, it becomes `sleep 2; ls &` and there the & affects only the second parameter.

Another solution would be to put brackets around the commands, `( sleep 2 ; ls ) &` **will** perform both actions sequentially:

```
system('( sleep 2 ; ls )', wait=FALSE)
```

Comment: I'm also baffled by this, especially since the documentation states that it is appending '&' to the call in order to support wait. Doing this in the terminal with multiline command works fine..? Anyway, your approach works.

Comment: That explains its weird behavior, I have extended the answer with that.

Comment: It is easy to confirm that R is just appending & to the command, look at the code for system... `if (!wait && !intern) 
        command <- paste(command, "&")`

Comment: Notably this results in inconsistent behavior between Linux-alikes and Windows; which seems to be a running story for system (unsurprisingly).

Comment: @rpierce I agree, it's quite sad. It boils down to their use of different shells. Although in this case I should note you don't have `sleep` nor `ls` on windows. :)